# trace-pid file not being generated. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, trace, qemu

I'm trying to generate the trace-pid file, but it isn't being generated. However instead of trace-pid file being generated, the entire output of that file is being printed on the terminal itself. Why is that happening? And how the file be generated?

I followed the following steps:

```
make

echo exec_tb   \> /tmp/events

qemu -trace events=/tmp/events
```